# Canon 85mm front glass spots problem

Tags: lens, spots

I have canon 85mm f1.8 lens but the front glass got a lot of tiny scratches and it's affecting the sharpness. Can it be repaired or replaced? How much does it cost?

Comment: Send the lens to Canon for a repair estimate. My guess is the cost to replace the front element will probably be about 300USD.

Comment: What makes you think tiny scratches on the front element, rather than something else, are what is "affecting the sharpness"? It takes a [LOT](https://wordpress.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/10/front-element-scratches/) of front element damage before it's noticeable in photos. See also [How can I remove scratches from a lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/71569/15871) and [How do I diagnose the source of blurry photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87861/15871)

Comment: @MikeSowsun Which is about the same price that good used EF 85mm f/1.8 can be bought in a lot of places.